# removing entire .idea from a git repository via pycharm

Tags: git, pycharm

I just migrated from atom/spyder to using PyCharm.  I am writing a larger codebase now, so I decided to use Git, as I figured that will make it easier to stage the codebase to a remote server later.  I'm totally new to Git.

I think I made a mistake, when creating the repository, of including the `.idea` subdirectory where Pycharm keeps all its own settings.  This is something that is specific to me working on my local windows7 box; it never needs to be included in the repository.

`workspace.xml` was constantly flagging as an updated file,  so I used `git -r rm --cached .\.idea\` to try to remove all of it.   the git shell seemed to succeed.

But when I go back into pycharm, and go to commit, it once again seems like it wants to update/add these files back to the repository?

[image]

Maybe I'm misunderstanding what's going on? But can anyone advise how to get to the point that git shell, pycharm, the repository all agree that .idea/ will no longer be maintained in the repository?

======================

I've created a `.gitignore` file at the same level as the .idea/
[image]

Pycharm also is told to ignore that directory
[image]

However, the log indicates it still wants to update/monitor these files:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi as you wanted you can **ignore globally** some files i guess is what you want and you can **ignore locally** some files.

If your (file wanted as ignored) are all ready staged you need to unstaged from repository :

```
git rm --cached .idea/*
//or
git update-index --assume-unchange .idea/*
```

Here how to do ***globally*** :

```
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global
```

add the this file .gitignore_global

```
.gitignore
.idea/*
```

Here you can do it ***locally*** on root project :

1) create file .gitignore
 add this :

```
.gitignore
.idea/*
```

All are done.

Comment: I suppose I create the .gitignore in the root directory of the repository?

Comment: @user3556757 yes where the project files a stored physically. In the same level as .idea file to be 100% sure.

Comment: afraid still hasn't purged this directory.  I have added some screenshots in my original post.

Comment: I edited the post, you need to purge by git rm --cached .idea/* and if he doesn't work you have to change the * one by one git rm --cached .idea rm -cached .idea/file_x ... all of this because you stagged this file when you did a git add and git commit ...

Comment: I did the 'global' solution and that seemed to work.  I ran `git status` and saw that the deletions of all the .idea\ files needed to be commited. So I did a final `git commit -m 'good riddance'` and that seemed to do it.

Comment: Ok the reason why you can't was the first git add or commit with .idea stagged but now it's ok ;) gl for the next, regards.